# Log internet access

Tags: iptables, netfilter, logs

For a WiFi hotspot I want to record each guest's internet access.
Not the full data, only source/dest/timestamp/duration.

I didn't found any open source software to do this.
Question 1: does someone know a software to log internet access ? TCP + UDP

So I plan to use netfilter/iptables.

My ideas with netfilter:

```
iptables  -A OUTPUT  -o eth0  -m state  --state NEW  -j LOG
```

This correctly log source and destination IP adresses and ports.
This correctly log TCP and UDP first packet.
I will have to also log INVALID packets (and RELATED ?).

But this does not log when the connections end.
Question 2: any idea to detect "end of connection" with netfilter ?

Comment: Are you really, really sure you want to log every single packet? That's a LOT of data.

Comment: @dirkt: "source/dest/timestamp/duration" != "every single packet"

Comment: I can read "not full data", thank you. Yes, I meant "source/dest/timestamp" (and not contents) of every single packet. That's a LOT of data. Logging a few hundred packets for diagnostic purposes is different from logging millions of packets during normal use.